# BTF Find Four Closest Sampling Directions

Tags: brdf, sampling, pbrt

I am trying to use the techniques discussed in [this](https://diglib.eg.org/bitstream/handle/10.2312/EGWR.EGWR03.167-177/167-177.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) paper to implement a BTF into PBRT. I am stuck on how to actually interpolate the weights of the four closest sampling directions.

At the BTF, I have converted $w_o$ and $w_i$ from cartesian to spherical coordinates in order to do a lookup in the table of BTFs. The samples are taken with the following properties:

$\theta$ light (and view angles) range from 0 to 75 in 15 degree increments. $\Delta\phi$ at each $\theta$ goes from 0 to (360 - $\Delta\phi$) at -, 60, 30, 20, 18 and 5 degree increments respectively. In a table:

| $\theta$ | $\Delta\phi$ (0 - (360 - $\Delta\phi$)) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | - |
| 15 | 60 |
| 30 | 30 |
| 45 | 20 |
| 60 | 18 |
| 75 | 5 |

How can I determine the four closest sampling directions given $w_o$ and $w_i$? Retrieving the values/weights seems trivial, but I don't really have a clue on how to determine the four nearest directions and just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

A simple table could be a good choice. There are a few approach's the suggestion I'll put here is just my take on the description, but it can be tweaked to your needs. In psuedocode:

```
const float table[6] = {0,60,30,20,18,5};
int table_index = asInt(floor(theta/15.0));
float result = table[table_index] * (theta > range);
```

The above is implemented as the step function in increments of 15. The last bit of the result is a range check that can be used to zap out of range values. `(theta>range)` evaluates to zero or one.

If this is a total miss on what you need let me know and I'll tweak it to help get closer.